# debugger does not return from calling function to callee function

Tags: r, rstudio

I have sourced my code and am doing debug(myfun1) on the code below. As seen in the image, I have a breakpoint set at line 13. [image]

My code is as follows

```
myfun1 = function()
{
  print("This is myfun1, before calling the myfun2()")
  myfun2()
  print("This is myfun1, after calling the myfun2()")
  print("Does the debugger come back to this point")
}

myfun2 = function()
{
  print("This is myfun2, before calling the myfun3()")
  myfun3()
  print("This is  myfun2, after calling the myfun3()")
  print("This is the last but one line of myfun2()")
  print("This is the last line of myfun2()")
}

myfun3 = function()
{
  print("This is myfun3")
}
```

These are the sequence of steps I use for my debugging

1. I start with myfun1 and then do 's' on line4 to step inside myfun2()
2. The debugger directly takes me to line 13 since I have a breakpoint
   set
3. Now I do 'n' within myfun2() a couple of times which takes me to the
   subsequent lines, ie line14 and line15 resp.
4. **But, if I do 'n' on line 15, I expect it to go back to myfun1(). However, it just exits**(I was able to get it to go back to myfun1()
   by setting a breakpoint in myfun1 after myfun2() is called(say in line5 or line6), but shouldn't it
   return even otherwise?)

See my debug log below

```
> debugSource('~/Desktop/foo1.R')
> debug(myfun1)
> myfun1()
debugging in: myfun1()
debug at ~/Desktop/foo1.R#2: {
    print("This is myfun1, before calling the myfun2()")
    myfun2()
    print("This is myfun1, after calling the myfun2()")
    print("Does the debugger come back to this point")
}
Browse[2]> c
[1] "This is myfun1, before calling the myfun2()"
[1] "This is myfun2, before calling the myfun3()"
[1] "This is myfun3"
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> n
debug at ~/Desktop/foo1.R#13: print("This is  myfun2, after calling the myfun3()")
Browse[2]> n
[1] "This is  myfun2, after calling the myfun3()"
debug at ~/Desktop/foo1.R#14: print("This is the last but one line of myfun2()")
Browse[2]> n
[1] "This is the last but one line of myfun2()"
debug at ~/Desktop/foo1.R#15: print("This is the last line of myfun2()")
Browse[2]> n
[1] "This is the last line of myfun2()"
[1] "This is myfun1, after calling the myfun2()"
[1] "Does the debugger come back to this point"
exiting from: myfun1()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the GUI for RStudio is just a wrapper to the basic debugging functions in R. Setting the breakpoint by clicking on the margin would be equivalent to calling `setBreakpoint().`

These functions untimely call `trace()` which operate on a function level. That is, the tracer replaces the current function with a new function that enables the tracing; and that replacement function include an `on.exit` call to stop the tracing when the function is complete. So after `myfun2` exits, the tacser is disabled so you can't debug inside the functions that call `myfun2` (is `myfun2`).

If you need to debug at a higher level, set your breakpoint at a higher level. I'm not sure if you can change your debugger in the RStudio GUI, but if you call `trace()` yourself you can call `recover()` rather than `browser()` which will allow you to jump to different parts of the call stack.

Comment: Yes--the RStudio GUI doesn't actually use `setBreakpoint` but it does something similar (and eventually delegates to `trace`).